# Cookie not persisting for servers in different ports

Tags: ajax, reactjs, http, cookies, http-headers

I have two servers:

1. A static file server, that is currently running a simple nodejs server on a set of static files that have been created using react. Currently , it is running on the same machine as server 2, but in production we plan to put it in aws cloud front (a CDN). These files communicate via ajax to server 2.
2. An api backend , which is running flask.

server 1 runs on port http://test_subdomain.maindomain.com:8000  and server 2 runs on http://test_subdomain.maindomain.com:5000

The issue I am facing is that the cookies are not persisting across multiple ajax calls, which means that Im unable to keep a user logged in.

When I try to login to server 2 from a rest client, this is my response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/19.6.0
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: session=.eJwdjsFqwzAQRH-l7DkHW1Ivhh5apAYHdkWMqNBeAq3d2JJ9cRKSKuTfq_Y0MMx7zB0O3-twGqE5r5dhA4eph-YOT5_QgNWvMoj2mcResTMyuN2Empbgu8SOE8UukUOJwkj0PFLZsg4_lCnxNtxIf0nrOVnfKo7vS-mq4I6ChKnR04QiVH8ezG1N2dwo92PJK7s-oe5m0kdFeZw57orPFPYtsttX1n9MrCnhEmrWc7Rb8wKPDVxOw_r_H4QSCh6_CwZGAA.DGSLDw.vpI20IaG1fJkABGOcr77ZyP3BQc; Path=/
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Thu, 03 Aug 2017 10:23:11 GMT
Content-Length: 161
Connection: close

{
  "user": {
    "id": 2424, 
    "name": "Xyz", 
    "profile_picture": null, 
    "referralBonus": null, 
    "referralCode": null, 
    "wallet": null
  }
}
```

From google chrome it is :

#### General

```
Request URL:http://test_subdomain.maindomain.com:5000/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:666.666.666.666:5000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

#### Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://test_subdomain.maindomain.com:8000
Connection:close
Content-Length:161
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 03 Aug 2017 10:24:51 GMT
Server:gunicorn/19.6.0
Set-Cookie:session=.eJwdjsGKg0AQRH9l6XMORvQi5CIjAaFbsowJ05fAGpNxnLmYFU0H_31nc6jLK6hXb7jep_5pofid5n4H1-EGxRu-fqAAo1thfVpNMHmj7MCKhkZ7j0eyKI_EaI4MBaW0qNuFQpWg6xZ2laBrc0zNGvsc5WxRxUj34uM_KwdKK-FQW3a4J-kW0uWIDhNWp4w-PvKovkcjZsVAniQ6LzzGzay51B7dzZvAAUMdSD8OsO1gfvbT5z-kWZrB9gcA-km6.DGSLcw.RltIYqt4y6E76lKVWI-H9PXMz58; Path=/
Vary:Origin
```

#### Request headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:46
Content-Type:application/json
Host:test_subdomain.maindomain.com:5000
Origin:http://test_subdomain.maindomain.com:8000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://cookie.beatest.in:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

What am I doing incorrectly ? I have tried this multiple browsers and none of them work. There is no cookie set in the cookies of any of the browsers